# What's the fastest a tourist can go terrestrially?

Tags: transportation, where-on-earth

Let's ignore planes on the ground, transportation vehicles in test phase that aren't in commercial operations, and special vehicles that a tourist cannot buy/rent/enter decently easily.

The fastest I'm aware of the Shanghai Maglev Train, which can reach 431 km/h. Since it began operation almost 20 years ago (December 31, 2002), I expect there currently exists some faster means of transportation on the ground.

Comment: Shanghai Maglev was an experimental line. The result of that experiment was... it's not profitable or cost-effective in the medium term to build more ultra-high-speed Maglev lines.

Comment: @xngtng but Chinese, Japanese and French firms are still actively developing ultra-high-speed trains.

Comment: For long term, yes. If it wasn't an experimental line approved under really unique circumstances, it would probably be built today 20 years later (e.g. Central Shinkansen). The development right now is for 20 years later (or earlier in response to climate change and urbanization challenges).

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for… as you identify in your question, the Shanghai Maglev [is the fastest train in the world in regular passenger operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-speed_rail#Speed), there is no faster car or boat which "a tourist can buy/rent/enter decently easily," and you rule out aircraft.

Comment: @mlc thanks, sounds like an answer

Comment: @xngtng: the problem with the Maglev is that it ends at Longyang Road at the outskirts of town in Pudong. In most cases you still need a substantial subway ride to get anywhere useful and the connection isn't great in the first place. For such a short distance, the top speed doesn't really make a difference other than bragging rights: The difference between 300 km/h and 431 km/h translates into a measly 50 seconds of saved travel time.

Comment: What is the point of the traveller being a tourist? I guess not even locals can easily buy/rent/enter those "special vehicles". It looks like a way to make an off-topic question. You could as well ask "how fast can a tourist throw a tennis ball?"

Comment: @SJuan76 that'd still be about traveling.

Comment: @Hilmar In my opinion it's worth travelling on it for the experience, iff you find yourself at the airport in Shanghai.

Comment: Is the Shanghai Maglev train still running at 430 km/h? I though I had read somewhere that they had reduced the operating speed significantly to save costs.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany. Sure, and I'm glad I did it. However, it's not my standard way to get from the airport to the city. It's more of a theme park ride and less of reasonable public transport option

Comment: @Hilmar thanks for the info! Why use a different way to get from the airport to the city? just curious.

Comment: Because it's difficult to transfer at Longyang Road and the location is far away from where I typically need to go. It's not that much more expensive to get a car pickup or I can just take Line 2/10 for much less money, easier transfer and about the same total time.

Comment: @SJuan76 To me "tourist" in this situation more means something that anyone has access to as opposed to something where access is only to a limited (probably very small) set of people.

Comment: Is this excluding fairground or theme park rides? Rollercoasters seem to top out well below 200 mph, and I'm not sure a drop tower could get faster purely by gravity, but maybe there are other rides?

Comment: @StuartF This is including fairground or theme park rides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mlc](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/94507/mlc) gave an answer in the comment section, which attracted 4 upvotes, indicating that the Shanghai Maglev is the fastest a tourist can go terrestrially:

> As you identify in your question, the Shanghai Maglev [is the fastest train in the world in regular passenger operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-speed_rail#Speed), there is no faster car or boat which "a tourist can buy/rent/enter decently easily," and you rule out aircraft. – [mlc](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/94507/mlc) [May 9 at 17:26](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/163664/whats-the-fastest-a-tourist-can-go-terrestrially#comment411879_163664)

Some interesting comment on the usefulness of the Maglev's fast speed:

> The problem with the Maglev is that it ends at Longyang Road at the outskirts of town in Pudong. In most cases you still need a substantial subway ride to get anywhere useful and the connection isn't great in the first place. For such a short distance, the top speed doesn't really make a difference other than bragging rights: The difference between 300 km/h and 431 km/h translates into a measly 50 seconds of saved travel time. – [Hilmar](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13971/hilmar) [May 9 at 20:48](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/163664/whats-the-fastest-a-tourist-can-go-terrestrially#comment411898_163664)

I'll mark it as the accepted answer till someone find something faster.

---

Other ideas:

- Drop towers: [Zumanjaro: Drop of Doom is the fastest drop tower ride in the world](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Zumanjaro:_Drop_of_Doom&oldid=1024221034#Records) but only goes up to 137 kph.
- Roller coasters: [Formula Rossa is the world's fastest roller coaster with a top speed of 240 km/h](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Formula_Rossa&oldid=1019780826).